# how to get the anchor tag values from an ajax response when the class is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
{
var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
response=response.split('^^--^^');
var buname=response[5].split('^^|||^^');
//rest code
}
```

The following code is the response of  my ajax request mentioned above. **The following is stored in the variable `buname`.**i.e. **buname contains the following:**

```
<li rel="Particulier" onclick="javascript:tabledata('','buunits','3','single','','','','','','','');" style="height:16px">
        <a href="#">Particulier</a>
         -------------^
     </li>
<li rel="PLH" onclick="javascript:tabledata('','buunits','1','single','','','','','','','');" style="height:16px">
        <a href="#">PLH</a>
      ---------------^
     </li>
```

**What i want to do:**

I want to get the values of the anchor tag in a javascript string or array.

**Desired Output**: (Particulier,PLH)

**What i tried so far**: From one of the answer in SO i tried the following code but this is not working as i don't have any class defined in the code given of mine.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.email');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    alert(elem.firstChild.getAttribute('href').substr(7));
}
```

I need javascript solution, **please don't give jquery solution.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just do a `document.querySelectorAll('a');`?  or do you have other anchor tags to avoid?  If there are other anchor tags, are the target anchors wrapped in a DIV of their own?

Comment: If I've understood you question correctly, you have only a string. If so, you can [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) a temporary `ul` element and use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName). From the returned collection you can read `textContent`s.

Comment: @Marc thanks for the reply.no i dont have other anchor tags to take care of,i just want to get the anchor or rel values from the above mentioned ajax response.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the reply,i have a ajax response now as i mentioned in my comment i want to store the rel or anchor value in a string or array,since i have no class name declared so its bit complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll on an individual element, not just document:

```
var response = "<li rel=\"Particulier\" onclick=\"javascript:tabledata('','buunits','3','single','','','','','','','');\" style=\"height:16px\">\n        <a href=\"#\">Particulier</a>\n         -------------^\n     </li>\n<li rel=\"PLH\" onclick=\"javascript:tabledata('','buunits','1','single','','','','','','','');\" style=\"height:16px\">\n        <a href=\"#\">PLH</a>\n      </li>";
// skip the above in your normal environment, of course; here for example purposes :)
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.innerHTML = response;
var links = ul.querySelectorAll("a");
// links now contains a list of the anchor tags, i.e. [<a href=​"#">​Particulier​</a>​, <a href=​"#">​PLH​</a>​]
var link_texts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    link_texts.push(links[i].innerHTML);
}
// link_texts now contains the text inside the links, i.e. ["Particulier", "PLH"]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.i am testing your answer in my actual code,will et you know in few minutes.

Comment: How does `querySelectorAll` works without appending `ul` to `DOM`?

Comment: It just does? I tested this in chrome's dev console and it works fine. Works in Firefox console too.

Comment: Yes but it is not cross browser. You need to add it to DOM.

Comment: In which browser does it not work? I just tried it in IE as well, and it works fine. The same code could also work even if we just replaced `querySelectorAll` with `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will solve your problem 
`var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.email').getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
var elem = elems[i];
alert(elem.getAttribute('href').substr(7));}`

Comment: i dont have any class named as email,this solution only i mentioned in my question

Comment: var elems = document.querySelectorAll('UL').getElementsByTagName("a"); for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) { var elem = elems[i]; alert(elem.getAttribute('href'));}

Comment: thanks for the answer kamlesh but i think i got the most optimized answer.but thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` does not work on elements that are not appended to DOM, so adding it with `display:none` and later removing it.

```
 var html = "yourHTML data recieved",
     div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = html;
 div.cssText = "display:none";
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 var elements = div.querySelectorAll('li a'), arr = [];
 for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i< l; i++){
     var ele = elements[i];
     arr.push(ele.innerText || ele.textContent);
 }
 div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V48dx/1/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.is your answer valid when the ajax response is stored in a variable like response as i mentioned in my question?

Comment: Yes it is, you just store your html response in `html` variable in above code. Rest all it will take care.

Comment: but this(jsfiddle) is not my desired output,i want them in a string or an array and also only one anchor value is fetched not the other

Comment: You mentioned desired output as `[Particulier,PLH]` in your question. What do you mean by one anchor not other?

Comment: please check your fiddle.

Comment: Arey baba! check the console for result. I am storing your HTML in textarea so that it will easier for me to retriever do not consider textarea at all.

Comment: but in my question i have not mentioned any textarea or the corresponding id :)

Comment: @RishabhRaj I am using textarea to store your html content. I mentioned that instead of textarea value you pass your AJAX response. You can remove the textarea. Al you need is code from var html = `your HTML response`. And use the code I have written as answer just refer Demo for POC.

Comment: i am comparing yours and collin's answer.but thanks a lot for your time and for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do it.

**HTML**

```
<li rel="Particulier" onclick="javascript:tabledata('','buunits','3','single','','','','','','','');" style="height:16px">
        <a href="#">Particulier</a>
     </li>
<li rel="PLH" onclick="javascript:tabledata('','buunits','1','single','','','','','','','');" style="height:16px">
        <a href="#">PLH</a>
     </li>

<br/>
<button onclick="getAnchorText();">Get Text</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getAnchorText() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        alert(elem.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

**Demo in this Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gtZz5/

Note: this gets the anchor text content, which is what your original question asked for (not the `rel` value).

Comment: thanks for the reply.is your answer valid when the ajax response is stored in a variable like response as i mentioned in my question?

Comment: Give it a try.  I guess I hadn't considered the ajax aspect. You might need to add the element(s) to the page as @redv's answer suggests.

Comment: i am trying and will let you know in few minutes.